# What's the difference between %define and equ in NASM?

Tags: nasm

Code:

```
%define x 0x03
x equ 0x03
```

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`%define` is a far more powerful way of doing macros, akin to the C pre-processor. In your simplistic case, there is not a lot of difference, using `x` in the source code will result in the constant `3` being substituted. There's a subtle difference in that `equ` statements are evaluated once, when they are first read and `%define` macros are evaluated whenever they are encountered in the source.

You can see the difference there between the two statement snippets:

```
addr   equ       $
       %define   addr $
```

In that case, `addr`, when encountered in the code, will have different values. In the first case, `$` will be the location of the assembly position at the place where the `equ` is. In other words, where it's *defined.*

In the second case, it evaluates to the assembly location at the place where `addr` is *used.*

Where `%define` shines is with something like:

```
%define thricexplusy(x,y) (3 * x + y)
```

or:

```
%define ctrl(c) (c & 0x1F)
: :
mov     al, ctrl('z')
```

(or even considerably more complex things) which allow you to pass parameters to your macro, something not possible with a simple `equ`.