# #define alternative in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Does Assembly (or at least NASM) have an equivalent to the C/C++ #define?

I want to do something like this:

```
#define i [ebp - 4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NASM:

```
%define i [ebp - 4]
```

Source: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html

edit:
Maybe "equ" is interesting for you, too. Have a look at this thread:
[What's the difference between %define and equ in NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691807/whats-the-difference-between-define-and-equ-in-nasm)

Comment: Another option would be using a macro.